# Mythic Arcane Cannon and multiple energy spell

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, damage, mythic-adventures

If I cast [mythic arcane cannon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/arcane-cannon/) and use its conducting ability by casting a spell with multiple energy types say shocking grasp that's been metamagiced to do half electricity and half fire. What does the cannon damage become?

If the half is split between the energy types, it would be 3d10 normal and 1d10 electricity and 1d10 fire (due to pathfinders rounding down).

If the half is equally given to both "other half is energy damage of the spell’s type", it could become 3d10 untyped and 3d10 electrical and 3d10 fire.

But which choice is the correct one when a spell has two (or more) energy descriptors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying "half damage" incorrectly. [Elemental Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/elemental-spell-metamagic/) specifically states

> split the spell’s **damage**, so that half is of that energy type and half is of its normal type.

*Damage* is not the same as *damage dice*. To find the damage of your Arcane Cannon, roll all 6d10 dice. Divide the *result* by 2 to find the untyped and energy damage. Divide the energy damage by 2 to find the electrical and fire damage.

Your maximum lost damage is 2 (for a number such as 31, where halving it loses a point and halving 15 also loses a point.

Comment: So, except for my incorrectly splitting of the dice when it should happen after, the half would be spread across all energy types present in the spell/ability instead of each type getting half. Makes sense.